# Clustering lists having maximum overlap with size restriction

Tags: java, python, c++, algorithm, machine-learning

I have the following group of numbers:

```
group1: 12 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 75 89 91 100 105 107 108 Group Size: 40
group2: 56 57 60 71 72 73 74 91 92 93 94 100 105 107 108 110 111 Group Size: 30
group3: 57 58 91 107 108 110 112 114 117 118 120 127 129 139 184 Group Size: 15
group4: 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 17 18 20 41 42 43 45 47 Group Size: 40
group5: 57 58 91 201 205 207 210 212 214 216 217 218 219 220 221 225 Group Size: 30
.
groupN: 50 51 52 53 54 210 214 216 219 225 700 701 702 705 706 708 Group Size: 40
```

Now I want to cluster together groups having maximum overlap such that after clustering, maximum size within a cluster does not exceed 90. For example here, the clusters are: (group1,group2,group3),(group5,groupN) and group4. The overlapping elements in the 3 groups are shown below:

```
Cluster1: (group1,group2,group3): 57 91 107 108 Cluster Size: (Group1_size+group2_size+group3_size =85 <90) 
Cluster2: group4: 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 17 18 20 41 42 43 45 47 Cluster Size: (group4_size < 40)
Cluster3: (group5,groupN): 201 214 216 219 225 Cluster Size: (group5_size + groupN_size 70 <90)
```

If I include group5 in cluster1 then its size will be 85+30=115 and I want to return a size<90, therefore I can not include group4 in cluster1.
The elements in the respective clusters after removing the duplicate overlapping elements are:

```
Cluster1: (group1, group2, group3): 12 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 71 72 73 74 75 89 91 92 93 94 100 105 107 108 110 111 112 114 117 118 120 127 129 139 184
Cluster2: group4: 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 17 18 20 41 42 43 45 47
Cluster3: (group5,groupN): 50 51 52 53 54 57 58 91 201 205 207 210 212 214 216 217 218 219 220 221 225 700 701 702 705 706 708
```

Is there some existing algorithm or technique which may help me achieve this clustering with size constraint.

I tried to form clusters by finding the common elements between any two groups and including in the group if cluster size after inclusion is <90. But is there any existing algorithm in any of the programming language libraries like C++,python,java which may help me achieve this efficiently. If not, then is there any existing algorithm which achieves the same.

If possible, it will be great if the algorithm is optimal also.

Comment: Well if you want to be naive, you can just create clusters until they're the size you want: 1. iterate through existing clusters; 2. if there is enough space remaining in any, add group there; otherwise create a new cluster. If you want to be optimal, maybe you can get somewhere from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem Good luck!

Comment: @Alegnem Thanks a lot for replying. Yes I do want to be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy optimal solution. One approximation is as follows:

1. Pick the group with the largest size. Let its size be x
2. Pick the largest group such that its size is less than 90-x
3. Keep repeating step 2 until you cannot find such a group
4. Remove the selected groups and repeat the process starting from Step 1

Eg. You would pick group1 (or group4 or groupN) first is step 1. In step 2 you would pick group4. Now the size is 80 and there are no groups smaller than 90-80=10. So stop and remove these two groups. In the next iteration, you will select groupN, followed by group2, and at last group3. In the last iteration you have only one group, that is group5.